# Android Studio Device Manager loses the devices that i create after closing the program

Tags: xml, android-studio

Im getting the message "User mydevicename no longer exists as a device" whenever i reopen Android Studio after closing.

It looks like for some reason android studio is changing the format of the file "devices" from .XML to .OLD everytime i reopen the program after creating a new virtual device. (This happens in C:\Users\Usuario.android).

I have alredy tried with some steps that i read here on questions made many years ago, but im still getting the same issue.
I expected to be able to relaunch the devices with the play button but i keep getting the yellow triangle with the exclamation mark.

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?